# How to understand or "debug" hanging / not starting `bash` from WSL?

Tags: windows-10, bash, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed [WSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl/about) and was using `bash` via PowerShell in the last few days without any problems. Super nice.

But now it doesn't start anymore, after typing `bash` it just hangs and does nothing.

`bash.exe` is listed in the "Details" tab of "Task Manager" as `00 CPU` and `708 K Memory` - no changes. This is matched in "Processes" where the "Microsoft Bash Launcher" is a subprocess of "Windows PowerShell" which all use 0% CPU and are doing nothing.

I am running current Windows 10 with all updates:

[image: Windows 10 Pro, Version 1709, OS Build 16299.19]

How can I debug the `bash` process to find out what is going wrong?

---

(Previous questions with similar name are all for earlier iterations of WSL, now solved bugs or generally about error messages, not hanging processes)

Unfortunately, [Microsoft's troubleshooting instructions for "Bash is hung"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/troubleshooting#bash-is-hung) are pretty useless and don't make any sense. Besides it's for them debugging any hangs, not for the user to fix his problem (which of course is ok - but doesn't help me in my case here)

Comment: Restarting Windows fixed the problem for now. I still would like to find out how to understand what is going on and how to avoid it.

Comment: What part doesn't make any sense? They ask for a dump and provide the steps on how to create and report it? Alternatively, you could download `livekd` and use that to debug the issue without crashing your system.

Comment: Step 1 already doesn't tell me where to change the dump type.

Comment: I don't have a Windows 10 at hand but in Windows 7 it's `Control Panel - System and Security - System - Advanced System Settings` and in the properties dialog, choose the Advanced tab, go to Startup and Recovery settings and choose the dump type under `Write debugging information`.

Comment: @janpio - Likely because it is well documented [here](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/memory-dump-file-windows-10/), [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/969028/how-to-generate-a-kernel-or-a-complete-memory-dump-file-in-windows-ser), and [here](http://mywindowshub.com/how-to-change-the-type-of-memory-dump-file-that-windows-10-creates/).  Considering the number of grammatical and spelling mistakes in your link I am not shocked the author wasn't more detailed.  Doesn't change the fact how you change what type of memory dump is generated hasn't changed since Windows XP.

Comment: @janpio - I don't see a question I can answer.  I can't answer the reason WSL is crashing because you have not provided that information.  You don't ask how to change the type of memory dump that is generated, so I can't submit an answer on how to do that (although I would love to do that), the question body itself doesn't ask a single question.

Comment: Anything in the event log? Have you uninstalled and reinstalled WSL?